# Ruby oauth2 gem - how to override the token refresh URL for refresh! method?

Tags: ruby, oauth, oauth-2.0

I am using the [ruby oauth2 gem](https://github.com/intridea/oauth2/), but for Adobe echosign implementation, the token refresh URL (`/oauth/refresh`) is different from the one the the gem expects(`/oauth/token`).

Is there an elegant way to do this (without changing the gem code to add the URL parameter there) ?

Answer (score 0):

Add a route that points refresh to token controller action using match